# Removing the borders from bootstrap accordion control

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the code to play with:

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/B3JecPBpTu)

```js
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
    $("span").addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
  });

$('.collapse').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
    $("span").addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">


    <div class="panel-group" id="accordionMessagesSetup">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMessagesSetup" href="#collapseMessagesSetup">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
                        Message Setup
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseMessagesSetup" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="container">
                    
                  <p> my content goes here... </p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I remove the borders around my panel, except for the top one? I want the top border but not the ones on left, right or bottom. 
Sorry if it seems too simple; I'm just new to whole web dev stack.

Comment: I added your code to your question for you, but in the future please make sure your questions asking "How do I do X to this code?" include that code pasted *in the question itself*! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the [border-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-width.asp) properties.

Check the CSS in this code: [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/ZdYzcpvl8j)

Comment: thanks, can I just use "border" instead of "border-width" and set its left, right, bottom to zero?

Comment: Using `border`, you have to redefine the `border-style` and `border-color`.
Instead, you can use `border-width: 1px 0 0`